# Como manter o setState usando o Router no React?

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Estou iniciando meus estudos com React a precisava de uma ajuda: eu tenho uma aplicação que mostra uma lista de "soluções".

Nela também tem um botão que vai para uma página nova (que eu programei via Router) capaz de adicionar mais "soluções".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando eu adiciono uma nova "solução" via `setState()`, ao voltar para a página anterior (a página que mostra todas as soluções) o state volta ao estado inicial e a solução adicionada é apagada.

Tentei pesquisar no StackOverflow em inglês e vi que eles tinham uma solução, que pelo que entendi, é uma dependência chamada HISTORY. Mas encontrei pouquíssima informação sobre isso, e ficou confuso a explicação.

Segue o código que faz uso do Router e também faz o `setState()`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          nome: 'Andamento',
          desc: 'Quando o contrato está em andamento e pode ser alterado'
        },
      ]
    }
  }

handleSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let nome = document.querySelector('[data-js="nome"]').value
    let desc = document.querySelector('[data-js="desc"]').value

    // SALVANDO O SETSTATE, TUDO CERTO!
    this.setState(prevData =>({
      data: [{nome: nome, desc: desc}, ...prevData.data]
    }))

    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact
              render={() => <SituacoesList data={this.state.data} />} />
            <Route path="/addnew" exact
              render={() => <SituacaoAdd data={this.state.data}
              handleSave={this.handleSave} />} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A classe que mostra os dados é uma classe simples que apenas mostra a lista de dados via `.map()`, ela não faz nenhuma alteração no `this.state.data`.

Se precisarem de mais alguma informação, é só pedir!

Segue repositório do GitHub com o código completo: https://github.com/BiancaPereira/react-incidents-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu bug está sendo causado pelo uso da TAG `<a href="/" onClick={this.props.handleSave}>Salvar</a>`. Utilizando essa tag você força que seja atualizado a página montando todos os seus componentes de novo, dessa forma perdendo todos estados que haviam sido alterados.

Utilizando o [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) é recomendável você utilizar o componente [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) que já faz todo o controle do seu browse history.

Quando você utiliza a tag  você força a atualização da página que faz uma requisição nova carregando os arquivos para o browser novamente sem necessidade. Utilizando o `Link` a página é atualizada sem requisições, utilizando a estrutura do React para renderizar de novo seus componentes. Ou seja, vai ficar muito mais rápido.

Para utilizar o `Link` basta você informar o path desejado da mesma forma.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// [...]

<Link to='/' onClick={this.props.handleSave}>Salvar</Link>

// [...]
```

Comment: Perfeito Paulo, era isso mesmo!